# Generate random matrix where the entries in each column are drawn from a different range

Tags: matrix, random

I know that you can generate an $m\times n$ matrix of random numbers by `RandomReal[range, {m, n}]`, where e.g. `range = {0, 1}`.

Is there a  way to generate an $m\times n$ matrix of random numbers ***and*** have each column entry be drawn from a different range?

My question is, if there is something analogous to `RandomReal[{range1,range2,...,rangen},{m,n}]` (which obviously does not evaluate because it is not supported).

My current solution to this problem is using `Map`; i.e.

```
 Transpose[
   Map[
     RandomReal[#,m]&,
     {range1,range2,...,rangen}
   ]
  ]
```

where `m` is the desired number of $n$-tuples of random numbers from $n$ different ranges that I need.

Is there a better alternative to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `UniformDistribution[]` in `RandomVariate[]`:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{3, 4}, {5, 7}}], 4]]
   {{3.42591, 6.11193}, {3.39102, 5.57834}, {3.34707, 5.5937}, {3.45374, 5.41282}}
```

Alternatively, you can use `RescalingTransform[]` on the results of `RandomReal[]`:

```
scaledRandomReal[ranges_?MatrixQ, n_Integer] := With[{m = Length[ranges]}, 
      RescalingTransform[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, m], ranges][RandomReal[1, {n, m}]]]

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; scaledRandomReal[{{3, 4}, {5, 7}}, 4]]
   {{3.42591, 5.78205}, {3.34707, 5.90748}, {3.55596, 5.57834}, {3.29685, 5.41282}}
```

Comment: Are there advantages to the first form (`RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[...`) over `Transpose[RandomReal[#,4]&/@{{3,4},{5,7}}]`?

Comment: Yes, that works too. I just didn't want to use slots.

Comment: I think I'll use `UniformDistribution` because it's easier to wrap my head around it; `RescalingTransform` is really interesting and it's kind of embarrassing not knowing anything about it even though it's a 10 years old feature; +1 for the people at Wolfram